# Error in converting range into Array of floating values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

How to convert Range having `start` and `end` interval as `Float` values?
I am getting error as `TypeError: can't iterate from Float`

**IRB Session**

```
irb(main):058:0> (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

irb(main):059:0> ('a'..'k').to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

irb(main):061:0> ((1.1)..(1.10)).to_a
TypeError: can't iterate from Float
    from (irb):61:in `each'
    from (irb):61:in `to_a'
    from (irb):61
    .........
```

Comment: 1.1 and 1.10 are the same value.

Comment: How is Ruby going to iterate a float? By 0.1? By 0.01? By 0.001? You have to help it understand the appropriate step value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(1.1..1.2).step(0.01).map { |x| x.round(2) }
  # => [1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 1.2]
```

Comment: Accepting it as this solution is quite closer to what I required. :)

Comment: You can omit the call to `to_a`, it is useless since you're calling `map`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify step you want to iterate with first:

```
((1.1)..(1.10)).step(0.1).to_a

#=> [1.1]     as range has only one element :)

((1.1)..(1.5)).step(0.1).to_a

# [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
```

Note however it is pretty risky as you might hit float rounding error and the result might look like:

```
[1.1, 1.2000000000000002, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5]
```

Use BigDecimals to avoid this.

Comment: If he's using Ruby 2.1, the new rational literals could also help: `(1.1r..1.5r).step(0.1r).to_a #=> [(11/10), (6/5), (13/10), (7/5), (3/2)]`.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
(1.1..1.2).step(0.01).to_a
# => [1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.1300000000000001, 1.1400000000000001, 1.1500000000000001, 1.1600000000000001, 1.1700000000000002, 1.1800000000000002, 1.1900000000000002, 1.2]
```

Hither you shell to convert `Range` into `Enumerator`, which could be transformed into an `Array` with `#to_a` method.

Answer (score 3):

Read [*Custom Objects in Ranges*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#class-Range-label-Custom+Objects+in+Ranges)

> Ranges can be constructed using any objects that can be compared using the `<=>` operator. Methods that treat the range as a sequence (`#each` and methods inherited from Enumerable) expect the begin object to implement a `succ` method to return the next object in sequence. The `step` and `include?` methods require the begin object to implement `succ` or to be numeric.

This will give you the idea, about what are factors made Ruby to throw you that error.